# typescript augment "rx" module => Invalid module name

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

I am writing a node module that also contains types, since I'm using it with a typescript project. The module depends on `"rx": "^4.0.6"`. This version of `rx` contains the types internally in `rx/ts`. What I want to do is augment the `rx` types with 2 custom functions.

Module structure

```
myModule
|-- ts
    |-- index.ts
|-- package.json
|-- tsconfig.json
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "rootDir": "ts",
    "outDir": "./dist"
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myModule",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm run build",
    "build": "../../node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.0.35",
    "express": "^4.0.35",
    "rx": "^4.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "~2.3.4"
  }
}
```

ts/index.ts looks something like the following (didn't include the implementation of all mentioned functions):

```
import * as Rx from 'rx';
import * as express from 'express';

declare module "rx" {
    interface Observable<T> {
        pipeValueExpressResponse: (res: express.Response) => void;
        pipeArrayExpressResponse: (res: express.Response) => void;
    }
}

// export some types...

Rx.Observable.prototype.pipeValueExpressResponse = function(res: 
express.Response) {
    sendValue(this, res);
};

Rx.Observable.prototype.pipeArrayExpressResponse = function(res: 
express.Response) {
    foldResponse(this, res);
};

// export some functions...
```

Compiling the module leads to `Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'rx' resolves to an untyped module at '.../myModule/node_modules/rx/index.js', which cannot be augmented.`

I have read a lot answers regarding module augmentation in typescript but wasn't able to fix my problem.

**EDIT**

Using a `/// <reference path="" />` to the included `rx` types in `rx/ts` solved the `Invalid module name` issue but now I get a `Property 'prototype' does not exist on type 'ObservableStatic'` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix the `Invalid module name` issue by adding a `/// <reference path="" />` to the `rx/ts/rx.all.d.ts` types in `index.ts`.

After that I got a `Property 'prototype' does not exist on type 'ObservableStatic'` error which I fixed by adding the following:

```
declare module "rx" {
    interface ObservableStatic {
        prototype: any;
    }

    interface Observable<T> {
        pipeValueExpressResponse: (res: express.Response) => void;
        pipeArrayExpressResponse: (res: express.Response) => void;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install the types for the `rx` module :

```
npm install @types/rx
```

Comment: I get `Duplicate identifier` errors doing so. And since types already exist in the `rx` module, I don't see why I should do that. I guess this would be my last solution, but even in this case, I still get a lot of errors.

Comment: @XeniaSis you should figure out where the duplicate types come from, maybe there are other definitions you have installed, I installed just `@types/rx` and I can augment the module fine. Try running the install in an empty folder and compile the code there and see that it works

Comment: Isn't there a way to just "import" the already included types? It also seems that the `@types/rx` are not complete/compatible with the version I use